# How to associate artefacts under one business version in Nexus when every module has specific version?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, nexus, nexus3

It is probably not a good practise in this case, because the problem would be solved by unifying the versions of all artefacts, but I am interested in a possible solution for this case. I have one git repository:

artefact -> 1.0.0

second git repository:

artefact -> 1.3.0

third git repository:

artefact -> 2.0.0

These artefacts go into nexus release repository with versions as I wrote but we define a business version above all of the mentioned artefacts for example 66.0. I would like to be able to marked artefacts with this business version and be able to return them from nexus. I did some research and found [tagging](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/tagging) in Nexus unfortunately available only for **Nexus Manager Repository Pro**, but we would like to use only free edition. Do you have some idea how to handle this problem?

Comment: If they are related as it sounds the best way would to make a multi module build of it so they have the same version ... ? And then you can simply use your business version..apart from that the question is why a business version does not follow semver etc. but I think this is a different story.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as you said, the problem is not how to define one common version for all of the artifacts (this would be solved by a multimodule Maven project). The problem is to associate every artifact with its own version belong to one release marked with a business version. The problem can be solved by specifying one version (it means business version) for all of the artifacts, but I am trying to avoid this solution. Hopes that I described it well.

Comment: The solution is in the end to migrate that into a multi module build cause that's exactly expressing what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a few considerations, we decided to set one common version to all of our components. There was no suitable way of how to select artifacts from nexus by the additional metadata.